# Run cloudwatch rule once the previous step function completes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I want to Run cloudwatch rule once the previous step function completes.

This needs to be done multiple times(you can say reusable).

Example- once I trigger a step function rule and its execution gets complete, the next cloudwatch rule shoud get triggered and so on.

Can this be done like- once step function completes, a message should be published to SQS and then using the sqs, a cloudwatch event can get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

We can create a [cloudwatch rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html) with Event Source on Step Function with status `SUCCEEDED`

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.states"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Step Functions Execution Status Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "SUCCEEDED"
    ],
    "stateMachineArn": [
      "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:555666611111:stateMachine:my-state-machine-qa"
    ]
  }
}
```

and add next Stepfunction as Target.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Since our stepfunction is used by multiple teams, hence it can have multiple executions. Is there any way we can have any kinda pattern match on the execution name?